# No me sale el ListView con Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Estoy empezando con Django, tratando de hacer mi primer listview con vistas basadas en clases. Tengo una tabla ciudades, el cual esta cargada con 10 registros.

La info es la siguiente:

- Postgres: versión 10 (PgAdmin 4)
- Python: versión 3.6.6
- Django: versión 2.0
- IDE: Visual Studio Code

**MODEL**

```
from django.db import models

class ciudad(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
```

**VIEW**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import ciudadForm
from .models import ciudad
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, View

class mostrarCiudad(TemplateView):

    model = ciudad
    template_name = "syslab/lista_ciudad.html"
    context_object_name = 'ciudades'
    queryset = ciudad.objects.all()
```

**URL**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import mostrarCiudad

urlpatterns = [

    path('lista_ciudad/', mostrarCiudad.as_view(), name = 'lista_ciudad')

]
```

**HTML**

```
{% extends 'index.html' %} 

{% block titulo %} Listado de ciudades {% endblock titulo %}

{% block body %} 

        {% if ciudades %}
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Descripcion</th>                        
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for ciudad in ciudades %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ ciudad.id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ ciudad.descripcion }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %} 
                </tbody>
            </table>        
        {% else %} 
            <h1> No existen ciudades registradas </h1>
        {% endif %}

{% endblock body %}
```

El servidor no me marca ningún error. Al ejecutar la URL, me sale siempre el mensaje: **No existen ciudades registradas**.  No consigo hacer el listado.

**Navegador**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Posgres**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que tu mostrarCiudad view no hereda de ListView, sino TemplateView. Sin tener una copia de tu código para probarlo, apuesto que el problema es que herederos de TemplateView no pueden recibir (ni entender) los variables, como "context_object_name." Así que trata de cambiarlo a ListView.

Como otra opción, si quieres usar TemplateView, puedes proveer los datos al template así:

```
class mostrarCiudad(TemplateView):

    template_name = "syslab/lista_ciudad.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["ciudades"] = ciudad.objects.all()
        return context
```

como en la documentación [aquí](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview)

Comment: En efecto amigo. Al cambiarlo por ListView, se resolvió el problema. Te lo agradezco mucho. Gracias.